# systemverilog static class member cannot be accessed via the class scope resolution operator

Tags: static, sequence, uvm

In my t1 extended uvm_test class I'd like to use the xxx_write method from a sequence class xxx_io in xxx_pkg.

I've imported * the package into my t1 class, and I've made the method static but I still receive the same error from compiler:

> ncvlog: *E,ILLCSS (/ddd/test.sv,82|29): A Non static class member cannot be accessed via the class scope resolution operator '::'.
>        xxx_pkg::xxx_io::xxx_write(12'h000, 32'h11ceb00c);

Since the error message did not change after I added the static key word to xxx_write method it would not surprise me if the error is elsewhere. But my code 'works' if I do not try to call this method from t1 class.

```
package xxx_pkg

class xxx_io extends uvm_sequence #(xxx_seq_item);

static task xxx_write( bit [11:0] i_addr, integer i_wdata );

// snip other code

endtask

endclass: xxx_io
endpackage: xxx_pkg


class t1 extends uvm_test

import xxx_pkg::*

class test1 extends uvm_sequence #(xxx_seq_item);

task body ;

     xxx_pkg::xxx_io::xxx_write(12'h000, 32'h11ceb00c);  

     // snip other code

endtask

endclass : t1
```

Comment: Does the static method reference any dynamic variables, such as a non-static local variable?

Comment: yes xxx_write calls a task that uses a instance of the xxx_seq_item to talk to the driver

Comment: Then that is part of the problem. A static method should only reference other static methods or variables, or dynamic variables/methods local to its scope (eg instantiated inside the static methods).

Comment: I'm looking but I don't see how to mark your comment as the answer, thanks Greg.

Comment: Why are you trying to call the method via static access? Why not create an instance of the sequence in the test then call the method from that instance?

Comment: Yes that is what I've done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Greg: create an instance of the sequence in the test then call the method from that instance